# C# how can i use WMI to create user account in a remote computer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wan to create user account in a remote machine and set some credintial to it.
i knew that we can use WMI to run batch file remotly on another machine .

is there a way to run batch file using c# code to create user name and passowrd remotly on another machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a batch file, it is possible to use the classes in System.DirectoryServices.

```
// you need to supply these parameters:
string domainName = "domain";
string computerName = "computer";
string userName = "name";
string password = "password";

var machineDirectory = new DirectoryEntry(@"WinNT://" + domainName + @"/" + computerName + ",computer");
var userEntry = machineDirectory.Children.Add(userName, "user");

userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", password);
userEntry.CommitChanges();
```